# How to calculate Variance after Convolution process

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to understand is it possible to say what variance I'll have if apply convolution to image. In my case I have matrix(image) and I am applying Gaussian Blur(with known parameters $\sigma_X = 1$, $\sigma_Y = 1$). Then I can easily calculate a variance of any row or column from matrix before and after convolution. So I did.
But is there any way to say what variance I get after convolution process known variance before, $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$.

Comment: Not really, because unless the image is white noise, columns will be associated with their neighbors and rows will be associated with their neighbors: and the degree of this association, as measured by their correlation coefficients, is a necessary part of the answer.